# Filtering option data in R

Tags: r, filter

I have data data like this

```
Date           Closing_price    strike_Price  Underlying_Value
01-01-2015     12                120           109     
01-01-2015     10                110           109
01-01-2015     5                 130           109
01-01-2015     3                 140           109
01-01-2015     15                100           109
01-01-2015     25                90            109
```

What I want is only those rows whose strike price is just above the Underlying Value and just below the underlying value. If `Underlying_Value` and `strike_Price` gets matched, then I want only single row.

Desired Output : (in this case)

```
 01-01-2015     10                110           109
 01-01-2015     15                100           109
```

Similarly, I have data for various date. `Underlying_Value` will vary across dates only. I want filter such data for each and every date and save them as data frame(in single object, not separately for each and every date).

I managed to write code, but it is taking too much time. For observation 82000, approx time is 3 min.

I want to know, is their any efficient way?

What I did :

1) First creating another variable within dataset df1$money <-( df1$Underlying_Value-df1$Strike_Price)/df1$Underlying_Value, 
2) Using loop, first selected rows, where df1$money greater than 0 and selected row having min value for df1$money, than where df1$money less than 0, i selected row having maximum vaule for df1$money.

It worked, but it is taking too much time...

My exact code is:

```
atmoney <- function(data) {

Date.i <- unique(data$Date)

len <- length(Date.i)

data$money <- (data$Underlying.Value-data$Strike.Price)/data$Strike.Price

at.first.row <- data[1,]

for(i in 1:len) {

data.f <- data[data$Date==Date.i[i],]

data.f.1 <- data.f[data.f$money >=0,]

data.at.1 <- data.f.1[data.f.1$money==min(data.f.1$money),]

data.f.2 <- data.f[data.f$money <= 0,]

data.at.2 <- data.f.2[data.f.2$money == max(data.f.2$money),]

at.first.row <- rbind(at.first.row,data.at.1, data.at.2)


}

desired_data <- at.first.row[-1,] #removed first row
}
```

Comment: What is the threshold for just above and just below?

Comment: If the threshold is `10`.  then `subset(df1, abs(strike_Price - Underlying_Value)<10)`  For multiple dates, `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(Date) %>% filter(abs(strike_Price - Underlying_Value) <10)`

Comment: Thnks, but there is no threshhold level.

Comment: You need to make a baseline to compare.  Anyway, I showed you an option to get the expected result based on the sample data.

Comment: what i did, i mentioned in answer 1 post. Problem is that it is taking too much time. I have data for around 5 years and for each date there are around 700 observations. Approximate time from my method is around 3 min.

Comment: May be this is what you wanted `indx1 <- setDT(df1)[, money:=(Underlying_Value-strike_Price)/Underlying_Value][money <0, .I[which.max(money)], Date]$V1;indx2 <- setDT(df1)[, money:=(Underlying_Value-strike_Price)/Underlying_Value][money >0, .I[which.min(money)], Date]$V1; df1[c(indx1,indx2)]`

Comment: You are absolutely right bro. But when i used loop and applied to large set of data having more than one dates, this function taking lot of times.

Comment: I would say this would be faster than your rowwise loop because we are creating new dataset by assigning `:=` and then get the row index with `.I` and subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need a cut off value to filter.  Using the above example, if I use `10` as the cut off limit

```
 subset(df1, abs(strike_Price - Underlying_Value)<10)
 #        Date Closing_price strike_Price Underlying_Value
 #2 01-01-2015            10          110              109
 #5 01-01-2015            15          100              109
```

For multiple dates also, the above would work

Using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[abs(strike_Price - Underlying_Value)<10]
 #         Date Closing_price strike_Price Underlying_Value
 #1: 01-01-2015            10          110              109
 #2: 01-01-2015            15          100              109
```

#### Update

Based on the edit, may be you can try

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, money:=(Underlying_Value-strike_Price)/Underlying_Value]
 indx1 <- df1[money <0, .I[which.max(money)], Date]$V1
 indx2 <- df1[money >= 0, .I[which.min(money)], Date]$V1
 df1[c(indx1,indx2)][,money:=NULL]
 #            Date Closing_price strike_Price Underlying_Value
 #1: 01-01-2015            10          110              109
 #2: 01-01-2015            15          100              109
```

Comment: Thnks, but there is no threshhold level. I want rows whose strike_price is just above the underlying_Value and below the underlying value for each and every date. What i did is i created another variable within data. Procedure is like this: 1) df1$money <-( df1$Underlying_Value-df1$Strike_Price)/df1$Underlying_Value, 2) Using loop, first selected rows, where df1$money greater than 0 and selected row having min value for df1$money, than where df1$money less than 0, i selected row having maximum vaule for df1$money.

Comment: @Neeraj You can update it in your post.  The way you did was also with a criteria.  Without mentioning that in your original post, I don't know how others are going to suggest a solution.  So, I used a threshold value.

Comment: @Neeraj Your criteria is confusing.  You said to first select rows with money greater than 0 and selected row having min value, then something about maximum value.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As you know i want only those row whose strike price is just above and below the Underlying_Value for each and every date. I did not find direct way, so i created another variable. As you created abs(Strike Price - Underlying value), then selected within threshold level ie 10. What i did is same. By creating it separate variable but not absolute. Since, some would be positive and some would assume negative values, i choose appropriate from them using max and min function. By using loop, i managed to did for all dates.

Comment: You are absolutely right bro. But when i used loop and applied to large set of data having more than one dates, this function taking lot of times.

Comment: @Neeraj I posted a code based on data.table.  It would be faster

Comment: Hi i have provided exact code now on my original post.

Comment: @Neeraj Thanks Have you tried the data.table solution and check if that is faster?

Comment: Thanks... i would try it also.

Answer (score 0):

I added a second date to your example, to account for multiple dates. This gives you the minimum values per day. You can adjust the formula's to the one you need.

```
  library(dplyr)

  df1pos <-df1 %>% mutate(diff = (Strike_Price - Underlying_Value)) %>% group_by(Date) %>% filter( diff > 0) %>%  filter(diff == min(diff))
  df1neg <- df1 %>% mutate(diff = (Strike_Price - Underlying_Value)) %>% group_by(Date) %>% filter( diff < 0) %>%  filter(diff == max(diff))
  dftotal <- union(df1pos, df1neg)

  dftotal

  Date Closing_price Strike_Price Underlying_Value diff
  1 01-01-2015            15          100              109   -9
  2 02-01-2015            15          100              108   -8
  3 01-01-2015            10          110              109    1
  4 02-01-2015            10          110              108    2
```

I assume the group by needs to be extended, to show the different stocks. But that was not clear from your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is exactly whats the doctor order... It is fast and most important does not require any loop and function..

Comment: @Neeraj This is similar to `data.table` and `data.table` should be equally or more faster

Comment: Actually i have no idea for package data.table.
I try most from inbuild package in R.
But now I have learned package dplyr. It is superb and easy to use.
One question : You appear to be expert in R then why donot you write your own function using basic packages provided in R, instead of using external package ?
I feel pain in neck for every new package.